# Checking if an attribute changed after commit in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I know that using `dirty` or `changed?` is useful in a `before_commit` situation or before the model is saved. After the model is saved, `previous_changes` gives the changes. Which is great. But,

How can I check if a specific attribute was changed in a controller if it looks like

```
def update
 @item = Item.find(params[:id])
if @item.update_attributes(item_params)
 # horray
 # check if the :name changed, if so do something about it
else
 # d'oh
end
end
```

Is there a better way than doing `!@item.previous_changes[:name].nil?`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I do not know if there is any better way, but I would do:

```
if @item.previous_changes.has_key?('name')
  # Name has been changed.
end
```

Answer (score 3):

In Rails 5 you can use `saved_change_to_attribute?` to check if the specific changes.